# Como sobrepor uma div de outra usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quando clico no + do meu select, meu sistema mostra e adiciona um item na div com "tabs".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

só que quando ele mostra a div que estava oculta, ela ficasse em cima do meu select (como mostra na imagem).

> função:

```
 function add(id_sistema){

    $('#tabs').append("<div id='tabs-2'></div>");

    $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    $("#tabs").show();
    $("#divDataJson").show();

}
```

Resumidamente é essa função quando eu clico no +.

Comment: se você pegar essa div a partir do id e adicionar um z-index nela não da certo? exemplo $('#tabs-2').css("z-index","1");

Comment: funcionou, essa eu não sabia obrigado. quer criar uma resposta?

Comment: irei criar obrigado @JulioHenrique97

Comment: não seria mais facil colocar o `z-index` no style dela na hora do append ali na string ao invés de utilizar jQuery para isso? `<div id='tabs-2' style='z-index: 1;'></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegue o id dessa div e adicione um z-index nela com a função "css" do jquery segue abaixo um exemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addZindex').on('click',function(){
    $('#exemplo').css("z-index","1");
  });

});
```

```css
#exemplo{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
}

#exemplo2{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  left: 30px;
}

#addZindex{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exemplo"></div>
<div id="exemplo2"></div>
<button id="addZindex">Mudar Z-index</button>
```